# How to output information in a Database specific to a user

Tags: php

I have been teaching myself code for the past 3 months now and I am working on a project that is outside my level of knowledge. So on the site we're creating, we have a page where the user creates a profile and anyone who visits the site see's that information, the information they input is stored in a database table. What I am trying to do is only display that information for that specific user. Right now I have created three different users and when I login to each one it displays the same information for each user. I am sure this question has been answered i just dont know how to word it. Below is the input form and .php file i am currently using.

```
<div class="modal-body">
                          <form action="edit_profile.php" method="post">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Name" name="name" required="">
                          <br>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="about_me" rows="3" placeholder="About Me (300 Characters Max)"></textarea></textarea>
                          <br>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="My Specialties" name="specialty" required="">
                          <br>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="City" name="city" required="">
                          <br>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="State" name="state" required="">
                          <br>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Email" name="email" required="">
                          <br>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Website" name="website" required="">
                          <br>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook Link">
                          <br>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" name="instagram" placeholder="Instagram Link">
                          <br>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter Link">
                          <br>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" name="google" placeholder="Google+ Link">
                          <br>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            <!-- End Edit Profile Modal -->

            <h4><strong>About Me: </strong></h4>
                <?php echo $row['about_me'];?>
            <h4><strong>My Specialties: </strong></h4>
                <?php echo $row['specialty'];?>
            <h4><strong>Location: </strong> </h4>
                <?php echo $row['city'];?>, <?php echo $row['state'];?>
            <h4><strong>Get Connected: </strong></h4>
                <h5><strong>Email:</strong> <?php echo $row['email'];?> </h5>
                <h5><strong>Website:</strong> <?php echo $row['website'];?></h5>
                <h5><strong>Facebook:</strong> <?php echo $row['facebook'];?></h5>

//DATABASE CONNECT
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="XXXXXXX";
$password="XXXXXXX";
$db_name="photographer_directory";
$tbl_name="qls3_profile";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM qls3_profile");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<?php

include_once('includes/db_connect.php');

$name=$_POST['name'];
$about_me=$_POST['about_me'];
$specialty=$_POST['specialty'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$state=$_POST['state'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$website=$_POST['website'];
$facebook=$_POST['facebook'];
$instagram=$_POST['instagram'];
$twitter=$_POST['twitter'];
$google=$_POST['google'];

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(name, about_me, specialty, city, state, email, website, facebook,   instagram, twitter, google)VALUES('$name', '$about_me', '$specialty', '$city', '$state', '$email',  '$website', '$facebook', '$instagram', '$twitter', '$google')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='insert.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

header( 'Location: userprofile.php' ) ;
?>

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Use a [`WHERE`](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-WHERE.asp) clause.

Comment: Where clause doesn't work for what I am trying to accomplish. Basically a user logs in and creates a profile, I need that information to display in their profile. I am looking all over this site and can't find anything that will work with what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a SQL `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE` clause. It is best if you learn if for yourself: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: THANKS! I prefer to learn it myself, I just needed to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: SQL_Where doesn't do what I am looking for. With SQL_Where you have to be specific for instance if I want to pull information from the database of people who live in say los angeles it will work, but I need it to pull the information based of the user that is logged in. So if Jon Doe is logged in then it will show his information. Is there a way to do this with the SQL_Where clause or do I need to go another route?

Comment: You know who the current logged in user is and the SQL row should contain the identity of the user it is describing. You can use the where clause to get the row that is appropriate for the current user.